# How to transfer the content of a map in a list without copying it

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `map<double, vector<double>>` say `myMap` that is fairly big. I would like to put the content of `myMap[.].second` in a `list<vector<double> >` or `vector<vector<double> >`. Is it possible to do it without copying explicitely each `vector` element ? I was hoping it was doable with `iterators`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double v_value[] = {1.1,2.4};
    vector<double> v(v_value, v_value + sizeof(v_value)/sizeof(double));

    map<double,vector<double> > myMap;
    myMap[10.01] = v;
    myMap[14.62] = v;
}
```

Comment: Yes, only if you keep the map arround. You just simple make a list of pointers.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The best you can do is make a list or vector of pointers, but you have to be careful that those pointers aren't invalidated by updates.

Comment: The `map<>` and the `list<>` should be distroyed at the same time so @andre condition should be met...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In c++03, you could use `std::vector::swap` for each vector in the map, into empty vectors in the list. In C++11, you can move from one to the other. Both avoid copying, but obviously modify the source map.

```
std::map<double, vector<double> > m = ....;
std::list<std::vector<double> > l(size_of_map); // list full of empty vectors
// iterate over map
typedef std::map<double, vector<double>>::iterator map_iter;
size_t list_counter = 0;
for(map_iter it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    l[list_counter].swap(it->second);
    ++list_counter;
}
```

In C++11:

```
std::map<double, vector<double>> m = ....;
std::list<std::vector<double>> l; // empty list

for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    l.push_back(std::move(it->second));
}
```